# set fragment tag when opening fragment using viewpager

Tags: android, fragment

here's  a portion of my code:

```
public class MenuExpenses extends Fragment {

    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expenses,container, false);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) root.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

        // Bind the tabs to the ViewPager
        PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) root.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setViewPager(viewPager);
        return root;
    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        private final String[] TITLES = { "Daily", "Recurring" };

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch(pos) {

                case 0: return new MenuExpensesDaily();
                case 1: return new IncomeList2();
                default: return new MenuExpensesDaily();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MenuExpensesDaily & IncomeList2 are both fragments. So how can I set the fragment tag for both of them here?

Comment: did you manage to get it working?

Comment: i just used different approach :D

Answer (score 0):

You can override the instantiateItem method, the save the fragment to a SparseArray/HashMap, then create a method to return the fragment with the position. Now you will be able to access your selected your fragment and set the tag to it.

Comment: I don't think that the right solution because fragmentManager stores the fragments and when activity recreates it still has the reference of fragments inside, meaning fragment manager will not call viewpager instantiateItem method and therefor data in the map doesn't get filled with correct values. I'm still looking for a better approach but not found it yet

Comment: @Alireza, When the activity recreate, the ViewPager and Adapter will also recreate as well. The instantiateItem will be called everytime it needs to display the page, instantiateItem will call getItem when the fragment isn't exist yet or it will get from the fragmentManager if the item is already created, so when you store the the fragment in instantiateItem, it will make sure you will get the right viewed fragment.